# How to parse and extract Year, Month, Day etc from time interval on iphone IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, nstimer

I am slowly getting into iOS development and trying to create a count up timer from a specific date. I have figured out the code which gives me the interval in seconds but I could not figure out how to extract Year/Month/Day/Hour/Minute/Second values from it in order to display each value in its own label as a ticker.

So far I have figured out that the following will give me the interval between the 2 dates in seconds, what I am trying to do is to parse this and display on my view this as a ticker by updating the UILabel every second using NSTimer and calling selector once every 1 seconds and get something like this on my view:

6Years 10Months 13Days 18Hours 25Minutes 18Seconds (obviously each label will be updated accordingly as the time goes up)

```
NSDate *startDate = [df dateFromString:@"2005-01-01"];

NSTimeInterval passed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: startDate];
```

Thanks

Comment: MB parse it mannualy by dividing time interval?

Comment: Just given a time interval this is not possible because months do not all have the same number of days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use NSCalendar with the two dates:

```
- (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)resultDate options:(NSUInteger)opts
```

Returns, as an NSDateComponents object using specified components, the difference between two supplied dates.

Example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2005-01-01"];
NSDate *endingDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

NSInteger days     = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger months   = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger years    = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger hours    = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minutes  = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger seconds  = [dateComponents second];
NSLog(@"%dYears %dMonths %dDays %dHours %dMinutes %dSeconds", days, months, years, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

NSLog output:

```
13Years 10Months 6Days 8Hours 6Minutes 7Seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as "month" and "year" will of course depend on which month and which year it is (365 or 364 days in a year? 30 or 31 days in a month?), you cannot just take the time interval and extract years and months - you always have to get a full date, e.g. by adding your (modified) time interval back to the start date like

`NSDate* newDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:modifiedPassedTimeInterval];`

From that date, you can easily extratc the year, month, and so on with **NSDateComponents**:

```
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:newDate];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents  year];
```

Comment: This does not provide the difference between two dates but rather the time since the startDate+timeInterval since the year 0.

Comment: indeed, you are right - you still have to do some more calculations to get the actual year / month / day difference. But there is no way around first getting an actual date if you want to get correct values.